# I want to add values into array which i use as property in object data structure in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

please i want to add some values into an array i have as property in my data structure but i wasn't getting it right. pls i need help. bellow is my code.

```
 const Question1 = document.querySelector('.qestion1').textContent;
const Option1 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="option1"]');
const Question2 = document.querySelector('.qestion2').textContent;
const Option2 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="option2"]');
const Question3 = document.querySelector('.qestion3').textContent;
const Option3 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="option3"]');
const Question4 = document.querySelector('.qestion4').textContent;
const Option4 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="option4"]');
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

const questions = {
  question1: Question1,
  correctAns: 'javaScript',
  question2: Question2,
  correctAns: 'CSS',
  question3: Question3,
  correctAns: 'Python',
  question4: Question4,
  correctAns: 'Html',
  choosenAnsers: [],
  getAns(Option) {
    Option.forEach(function (opt1) {
      opt1.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        const chosenAns = e.target.value;

        this.choosenAnsers.push(chosenAns);
      });
    });
  },
};

console.log(questions.question1);
questions.getAns(Option1);
```

here is my Html

```
<p class="qestion1">Q1: What is your favorite programming language</p><br />

    <input type="radio" name="option1" value="javaScript" id="A1" />
    <label for="A1"> A: javaScript</label><br />
    <input type="radio" name="option1" value="Python" id="B1" />
    <label for="B1"> B: Python</label><br />
    <input type="radio" name="option1" value="Rust" id="C1" />
    <label for="C1"> C: Rust</label><br />
    <input type="radio" name="option1" value="C++" id="D1" />
    <label for="D1"> D: C++</label><br />
```

and there is the error am getting

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
at HTMLInputElement. (questionScript.js:42:28)

Comment: @RezaSaadati that's not true if they are radio inputs.

Comment: i have multiple element with name="option1"

Comment: This will not work at all, since you have 4 properties inside ``questions`` with the same value ``correctAns``, resulting in a single prop, with the last declared value.

Comment: pls how should i write it so that it will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I`ve seen in you examples your JavaScript and your HTML has a lot of typos, and would not work.

The `questions` is this snippet is an array, that can be used to have more questions in it, and although I did`nt make the HTML write itself, this should give a concept of how it should work.

```js
const questions = [
  { 
    question: "Q1: What is your favorite programming language",
    name: 'question1',
    options: [
        'JavaScript',
      'Python',
      'Rust',
      'C++'
    ],
    correct: 'JavaScript',
    isCorrect: function () {
        var radios = document.getElementsByName('question1');

      for (let i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked && radios[i].value == this.correct) {          
          return true;
        }
      }
      
      return false;
    }
  },
];

function confirmChoices() {
    for (let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    console.log(questions[i].isCorrect());
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="qestion1">Q1: What is your favorite programming language</p>
<br />
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="JavaScript" id="A1" />
<label for="A1"> A: JavaScript</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="Python" id="B1" />
<label for="B1"> B: Python</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="Rust" id="C1" />
<label for="C1"> C: Rust</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="C++" id="D1" />
<label for="D1"> D: C++</label><br />

<button onclick="confirmChoices()">Confirm</button>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, i draw much inspiration from the assistance you gave me. I observe that i cant breakout of forEach loop when a certain condition is met. your assistance went a long way. am so grateful

Answer (score 0):

the value of `this` inside of an event listener is going to be the HTML element that is the event's `currentTarget`, so basically whatever you attached the event listener to. `this` will not be the `questions` const as you seem to expect.

A few more things:

you have multiple object properties all trying to use the same name `correctAns`, which will not work. answers has a 'w' in it.